Are there Dirac equations for different energy-momentum dispersion relations?
When I was introduced to the Dirac equation they wrote a PDE such that plane waves satisfy $E^2 = P^2 + m^2$. They went on to show that other options (ie Klein–Gordon) don't have spin.
Are there Dirac equations for other energy-momentum dispersion relations (ie $E^3 = P^5 + P^2$) and do these also have a notion of spin?

There is plenty of literature on Dirac operators for different PDEs. It's the same general process of taking a square root of the PDE.

You can write equations for whatever dispersion relation you come up with, but it is usually of no physical interest. Note also that this is independent from whether waves have spin or not. Let us take the one you gave as an example:
If you were looking for plane waves $\psi(x)$ with $E^3=P^5+m^2$, all you have to do is write the following equation
\begin{equation}
\left(E^3-P^5+m^2\right)\psi(x)=0
\end{equation}
and replace
\begin{align}
E & \; \to \; -i \partial_{0} \\
p_{i} & \; \to \; -i\partial_{i}
\end{align}
This is very unlikely however to show up in physics because

Equations higher than order 2 in time (i.e. having terms such as $\frac{\partial^3\psi}{\partial t^3}$) require more initial data than simply the value $\psi(t=0)$ and velocity $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}(t=0)$ of the field.
There is no way you can manage to write a Lorentz scalar that gives $E^3-P^5+m^2$, so the equation will not be invariant under the Lorentz group (which is actually the point of writing relativistic equations), meaning the dispersion relation will look different in frames moving at different relative velocities.

So in fact all relativistic wave equations have to satisfy $E^2=P^2+m^2$, which does not have the problems I have just mentioned. Note however that this holds independently of spin. Scalar, Dirac and Maxwell fields (or waves if you will) are spin $s=0,\tfrac{1}{2},1$ representations respectively and all satisfy the same dispersion relation. Spin has rather to do with what indices you equip the field (or wave) and, more precisely, with a prescription of how those indices mix up under Lorentz transformations.
